# Выбор элементов с заданным классом из объекта JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как из группы элементов, возвращаемых функцией JQuery, выбрать содержащие определенный класс?

Допустим, имеется такой html файл:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--Подключение стилей, скриптов, etc-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="class_1"></div>
    <div class="class_1 class_2"></div>
    <div class="class_1"></div>
    <div class="class_1 class_2"></div>
    <div class="class_1 class_2"></div>
    <div class="class_1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

И js:

```
$(function () {
    var items = $(".class_1");
});
```

Как через переменную `items` получить группу элементов с классом `__class_2__`?

Comment: Почему их нельзя сразу выбрать? А так - через `.filter()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var items = $(".class_1");
var class2Items = $(items).filter(function() {
  return $(this).hasClass('class_2');
});

$(class2Items).css('background', '#ff0000');
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class_1"></div>
<div class="class_1 class_2"></div>
<div class="class_1"></div>
<div class="class_1 class_2"></div>
<div class="class_1 class_2"></div>
<div class="class_1"></div>
```

Comment: `$(".class_1").filter(".class_2").css('background', '#ff0000');`